# "Work on the field" vs. "work in the field"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

Which of these is correct, or are both?

> 1. The farmer works on the field.
>    2. The farmer works in the field.

Hi, my name is Jahidul. I am a Bangladeshi Canadian. Based on my TOEFL, University and College education in Canada and with my 30 years of living in the US and Canada, I can well be self-assertive by saying that -

with respect to games and sports we say sentences like ' All the players are on the field now'. 'They are waiting for the coach to come on the field'.

When someone does work in the way of cultivating, weeding, harvesting etc., in a farm land then we can say like - (if someone asks you) 'where is Umaier?'. You can say, Umaier is working in the rice field.

On the other hand, we can say like - 'He won a medal on the field of battle'.

Then we also can say like -

'Russian aircraft SU 35Ss did very well in the field.'

'Michael E. Porter's theory of 5 Forces does not stack up against the truth in the field.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please consider asking this on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Both will work; depending on the contextual meaning required.

Answer (score 7):

> The farmer works on the field.

This means that the farmer does his work on the surface of the field. It can refer to the farmer himself being on the field while he works, or it can refer to the crops or livestock that are on the field.

> The farmer works in the field.

This means that the farmer works in the place referred to as the field.

~~~

Both statements answer (with nuances mentioned above) the following question:

> Where does the farmer work?

But if the question was:

> Where is the farmer now?

The answer is usually:

> He is in the field.